# nuxt axios onError unathenticated logout then redirect

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

my backend in laravel and i set if user login to another device then current device auth token is invalid

i also want if he get unathenticated error 401 in axios then instant logout and redirect to login page

i am doing like this

```
export default function({ $axios, redirect, $auth }) {
  $axios.onError(error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      if ($auth.loggedIn) {
        $auth.logout();
      }
      redirect("/login");
    }
  });
}
```

but nothing happen and when i check `console.log($auth)` its getting `undefine`

Help me thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to access $auth from $axios plugin, you can use auth.plugins option.

https://auth.nuxtjs.org/recipes/extend.html

```
{
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/auth'
  ],
  auth: {
     plugins: [ { src: '~/plugins/axios', ssr: true }, '~/plugins/auth.js' ]
  }
}
```